# Converting latitude and longitude coordinates from CSV using web service

Tags: python, csv, sqlite, geospatial

I am working on converting a mailing list that has longitude and latitude coordinates within the CSV file. This script I came up with does what I need, but this is my first real-world use of python. I want to know where I am making any mistakes, not using best-practices, and what can be optimized to make it faster.

The input.csv file has the following header:

```
"Email Address",MEMBER_RATING,OPTIN_TIME,OPTIN_IP,CONFIRM_TIME,CONFIRM_IP,LATITUDE,LONGITUDE,GMTOFF,DSTOFF,TIMEZONE,CC,REGION,LAST_CHANGED,LEID,EUID
```

And the script:

```
import sys
import os
import csv
import signal
import json
import urllib
import urllib2
import sqlite3
import codecs
import cStringIO

csv.field_size_limit(sys.maxsize)


class EmailList:

    WEB_SERVICE_URL = 'http://open.mapquestapi.com/nominatim/v1/reverse.php?format=json'

    def __init__(self, inputFile):
        signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, self.signal_handler)
        self.conn = None
        self.initialize_database(inputFile)
        self.convert_rows()
        self.db_to_csv()

    def signal_handler(self, signal, frame):
        try:
            self.conn.commit()
            self.conn.close()
            print '[DB changes committed and connection closed.]'
        except sqlite3.ProgrammingError as e:
            print '[script stopped]'
            print e.message

        sys.exit(0)

    def initialize_database(self, file):

        print 'checking for data.db...'

        if not os.path.isfile('data.db'):

            print 'data.db does not exist, converting csv to sqlite...'

            with open(file) as inputFile:
                reader = UnicodeReader(inputFile)

                header = reader.next()

                if self.conn is None:
                    self.conn = sqlite3.connect('data.db')

                c = self.conn.cursor()

                c.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS email_list")

                sql = """CREATE TABLE email_list (\n""" + \
                      ",\n".join([("%s varchar" % name) for name in header]) \
                      + ")"

                c.execute(sql)

                for line in reader:
                    if line:
                        try:
                            c.execute('INSERT INTO email_list VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', line)
                        except sqlite3.ProgrammingError as e:
                            print e.message
                            print line

                try:
                    c.execute('ALTER TABLE email_list ADD COLUMN CITY varchar')
                    c.execute('ALTER TABLE email_list ADD COLUMN STATE varchar')
                    c.execute('ALTER TABLE email_list ADD COLUMN COUNTRY varchar')
                    c.execute('ALTER TABLE email_list ADD COLUMN POSTAL_CODE varchar')
                except sqlite3.OperationalError as e:
                    print 'error creating new columns: '
                    print e.message

                self.conn.commit()
                self.conn.close()

            print 'converted csv to sqlite, stored in data.db'

    def convert_rows(self):

        print 'converting coordinates...'

        self.conn = sqlite3.connect('data.db')
        c = self.conn.cursor()

        results = c.execute('SELECT LATITUDE AS lat, LONGITUDE AS lon, Email as email FROM email_list WHERE POSTAL_CODE IS NULL AND CITY IS NULL AND COUNTRY IS NULL AND STATE IS NULL')

        rows = []

        for row in results:
            lat, lon, email = row
            data = {'lat': lat, 'lon': lon, 'email': email}
            rows.append(data)

        self.conn.commit()
        self.conn.close()

        for item in rows:
            try:
                converted = self.convert_coordinates(item['lat'], item['lon'])
                print str(rows.index(item) + 1) + '/' + str(len(rows))
            except TypeError:
                converted['city': '']
                converted['state': '']
                converted['country': '']
                converted['postal_code': '']

            self.conn = sqlite3.connect('data.db')
            c = self.conn.cursor()

            try:
                c.execute('UPDATE email_list SET CITY=?, STATE=?, COUNTRY=?, POSTAL_CODE=? WHERE Email=?', [converted['city'], converted['state'], converted['country'], converted['postal_code'], item['email']])
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                print 'user quit'

            self.conn.commit()
            self.conn.close()

        print 'converted coordinates.'

    def convert_coordinates(self, lat, lon):
        if lat and long:
            try:
                values = {'lat': lat, 'lon': lon}
                data = urllib.urlencode(values)
                request = urllib2.Request(self.WEB_SERVICE_URL, data)
                response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
            except urllib2.HTTPError as e:
                print 'error loading web service'
                print e.message

            json_result = json.load(response)

            try:
                city = json_result['address']['city']
            except KeyError:
                city = ''

            try:
                state = json_result['address']['state']
            except KeyError:
                state = ''

            try:
                cc = json_result['address']['country_code']
            except KeyError:
                cc = ''

            try:
                postal_code = json_result['address']['postcode']
            except KeyError:
                postal_code = ''
        else:
            city = ''
            state = ''
            cc = ''
            postal_code = ''

        return {'city': city, 'state': state, 'country': cc, 'postal_code': postal_code}

    def db_to_csv(self):

        print 'beginning write to csv...'

        self.conn = sqlite3.connect('data.db')
        c = self.conn.cursor()
        c.execute('SELECT * FROM email_list')

        with open('output.csv', 'wb') as outputFile:
            writer = UnicodeWriter(outputFile)
            writer.writerow([i[0] for i in c.description])
            writer.writerows(c)

        print 'write finished.'

        self.conn.commit()
        self.conn.close()

        print 'done.'


# The CSV module has issues with reading/writing unicode,
# the following classes were taken from docs.python.org to
# help with that: http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html


class UTF8Recoder:
    """
    Iterator that reads an encoded stream and reencodes the input to UTF-8
    """
    def __init__(self, f, encoding):
        self.reader = codecs.getreader(encoding)(f)

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        return self.reader.next().encode("utf-8")


class UnicodeReader:
    """
    A CSV reader which will iterate over lines in the CSV file "f",
    which is encoded in the given encoding.
    """

    def __init__(self, f, dialect=csv.excel, encoding="utf-8", **kwds):
        f = UTF8Recoder(f, encoding)
        self.reader = csv.reader(f, dialect=dialect, **kwds)

    def next(self):
        row = self.reader.next()
        return [unicode(s, "utf-8") for s in row]

    def __iter__(self):
        return self


class UnicodeWriter:
    """
    A CSV writer which will write rows to CSV file "f",
    which is encoded in the given encoding.
    """

    def __init__(self, f, dialect=csv.excel, encoding="utf-8", **kwds):
        # Redirect output to a queue
        self.queue = cStringIO.StringIO()
        self.writer = csv.writer(self.queue, dialect=dialect, **kwds)
        self.stream = f
        self.encoder = codecs.getincrementalencoder(encoding)()

    def writerow(self, row):
        self.writer.writerow([s.encode("utf-8") for s in row])
        # Fetch UTF-8 output from the queue ...
        data = self.queue.getvalue()
        data = data.decode("utf-8")
        # ... and reencode it into the target encoding
        data = self.encoder.encode(data)
        # write to the target stream
        self.stream.write(data)
        # empty queue
        self.queue.truncate(0)

    def writerows(self, rows):
        for row in rows:
            self.writerow(row)


EmailList('input.csv')
```

Comment: I like how you did not try to implement CSV parsing yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things that pop out for me immediately:

- You named a parameter "file", which is a built-in function in python.
- In one of your except blocks, you incorrectly use a dictionary.

See below:

```
converted['city': '']
converted['state': '']
converted['country': '']
converted['postal_code': '']
```

Note, what that will do is attempt to use the slice operator on the dictionary. I just tried it now and it fails with a TypeError exception. What you want the code to look like is this:

```
converted['city'] = ''
converted['state'] = ''
converted['country'] = ''
converted['postal_code'] = ''
```

Another thing I've noticed. Dealing with dictionaries, you're not quite sure how to handle getting "optional" parameters from them. Have a look at the refactored code I wrote for your json dict handling:

```
city = json_result['address'].get('city', '')
state = json_result['address'].get('state', '')
cc = json_result['address'].get('country_code', '')
postal_code = json_result['address'].get('postcode', '')
```

The get method on dictionary objects takes an optional second parameter that specifies a default value to return if the key is not found.

Comment: I don’t think `file` is a keyword in Python. It’s still a bad variable name, but not as bad as, say, `list`.

Comment: @alexwlchan Have a look here for the built-ins: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#file

Comment: Ah, sorry, I was taking “reserved keyword” a bit too literally, and thought you meant on of the [`keyword` keywords](https://docs.python.org/2/library/keyword.html).

Comment: @alexwlchan Np, and thanks... I've edited the answer to clarify a little better.